# Fullcalendar eventLimittext day value

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Hi I need to get eventlimittext day value.I shows and calls function when evenlimit exceed.

So I can get day value in eventLimitClick like

```
//in creating calendar

eventLimitClick :moreClicked,


function moreClicked(cellInfo, jsEvent) {  
    var event = cellInfo.date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    console.log(event)
```

I just gotta get the day value which exceed the limit

```
eventLimitText: function (numEvents) {
        //var event = cellInfo.date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        console.log("numEvents");
        console.log(numEvents);
```

In success i can get value but I can't get the day to pass controller with start data parameter. How can I get it

Thank you

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/GetCountByDay',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
         
            success: function (succ) {
```

Comment: I really need this, is there anyway

Comment: Why do you need this? Surely your server should already be able to know which days exceed the limit - assuming it was the server which provided the event data originally.